# Evaluating this integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral in matlab:
[image]
Here is my code:

```
alpha = 2;
F1 = @(u,v) 2*u.^2.*v./(1+2*z.*u.*v);  
F2 = @(v) v;
F3 = @(z) exp(-z)./sqrt(z);
I1 = dblquad(F1,0,1e5,2,1e5);
I2 = quad(F2,2,1e5);
quad(F3*exp(-(I2-I1)),0,1e5);
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
Error in ==> @(u,v)2*u.^2.*v./(1+2*z.*u.*v)


Error in ==> dblquad>innerintegral at 73
fcl = intfcn(xmin, y(1), varargin{:}); %evaluate only to get the class below

Error in ==> quad at 76
y = f(x, varargin{:});

Error in ==> dblquad at 53
Q = quadf(@innerintegral, ymin, ymax, tol, trace, intfcn, ...
```

These errors don't say much. Any help is appreciated. I'm choosing `1e5` to represent infinity.

Comment: What errors are you getting, exactly? Without knowing what errors you are getting, it's hard to tell what is going wrong. At a glance, I would suggest that you change the F1 function so that it does element-wise division, as opposed to matrix division (I doubt this is what you intended). I.e. replace `F1 = @(u,v) f(u,v)/(2*z);` with `F1 = @(u,v) f(u,v)./(2*z);`

Comment: `F1` has `z` in its definition. What is `z`? Also, `F3` is a function, you cannot treat is a simple variable and multiply it by something, you need to evaluate it by feeding it with input first.

Comment: @ Eitan `z` is the same variable in the outer integeral.

Comment: @ MrAzzaman I tried that also.

Comment: From the errors, it looks to me like the issue is in your function `f`, so without seeing that I don't think that we can help. Also can't `dblquad` and `quad` handle `Inf` to represent infinity (it's often more accurate to explicitly indicate integration to infinity). And are you using an old version Matlab? If not you should try [`integral2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) and [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html).

Comment: @horchler I just edited the question to explicitly show the functions. I'm using an old version of Matlab, so I don't have integral2

Comment: One issue is that `2*u.^2.*v./(1+2*z.*u.*v)` doesn't converge on `[0, Inf]`. Changing the upper bound to `1e5` is unlikely to give you a useful answer (it will just approach infinity as you increase the bound). Where is this expression from? Is `2*u.^2.*v./(1+2*z.*u.*v)` a simplification from some other expression?

Comment: @horchler True, it's just a simplification for some other long expression. I guess my main concern is that I might not be defining the functions correctly. For example I defined `F1` as a function of `u`and `v`, but there a variable `z` in there too, which is the same as the variable in the outer integral, so I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: That's another issue. You're right. If you do this numerically, you'll either need to factor `z` out of that, turn this into a triple integral and try `triplequad`, or define a mesh for `z`, evaluate the interior integrals at each of the mesh values, and then integrate those values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I properly write this integration in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665025/how-do-i-properly-write-this-integration-in-matlab)