# How do I properly write this integration in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral in matlab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZg5e.png

Here is my code:

```
alpha = 2;
F1 = @(u,v) 2*u.*v.*exp(-u.^2)./(1+2*z.*u.*v);  
F2 = @(v) v;
F3 = @(z) exp(-z)./sqrt(z);
I1 = dblquad(F1,0,1e5,2,1e5);
I2 = quad(F2,2,1e5);
quad(F3*exp(-(I2-I1)),0,1e5);
```

I'm getting the errors shown below. These errors don't show much, but I'm guessing it's because of the way I wrote `F1`. I defined `F1` as a function of `u` and `v` for the double integral, but there is also a variable `z` which is the variable of the outer integral. I did that because there is no way I can separate `z` from the inner integrals. Is there any better way to write this integration?

```
Error in ==> @(u,v)2*u.*v.*exp(-u.^2)./(1+2*z.*u.*v)


Error in ==> dblquad>innerintegral at 73
fcl = intfcn(xmin, y(1), varargin{:}); %evaluate only to get the class below

Error in ==> quad at 76
y = f(x, varargin{:});

Error in ==> dblquad at 53
Q = quadf(@innerintegral, ymin, ymax, tol, trace, intfcn, ...
```

I'm choosing `1e5` to represent infinity.

Comment: You are telling us where the error is raised, but not what the error message is.

Comment: @DanielR These are all the error messages I'm seeing in Matlab.

Comment: Well, running it on my system there surely is another message: `Undefined function or variable 'z'.`

Comment: @A.Donda I don't get that error, I'm running an older version of Matlab. But that could possibly be the error, I believe the way I defined `F1` is not correct, but I don't know of any other way. Any suggestions?

Comment: @A.Donda Thanks. I'll see if I can get any help from math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After having successfully answered a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696212/nested-numerical-integration/19715327) by the same poster, I realize a relevant part of this answer is wrong. I'd delete the answer, but I can't, since it is accepted. Therefore this disclaimer...*

---

The simple answer is: Your definition of `F1` contains a reference to `z`, but it is not specified as an argument of that function.

However, it won't help to specify `z` as an additional argument, because then `I1` is no longer a constant, but itself a function of `z`.

<s>I'm not an expert on numerical integration, but as far as I can see this means that you cannot numerically integrate your expression, at least not using a combination of `quad` and `dblquad`. The argument to the outer exponential function is just not a constant, and a numerical integration cannot return a function.</s>

It might be possible to rearrange the integral to bring it into a form that can be numerically integrated, but I can't tell you how.

Another problem is that "representing" infinity by 10^5 is not necessarily a useful approximation – it all depends on the behavior of the function that is being integrated. A possible trick might be to do a variable substitution such that each variable that goes to infinity is written as a function of another variable with a limited range.

My recommendation: Try to get as far as possible evaluating this integral *analytically*, and only use numerics when you are sure there is no analytical approach. And try to get help on that on math.stackexchange.com, because it is not a programming problem.