# Approximating a double integral in MATLAB by double summation

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am trying to approximate a double integral numerically using MATLAB by using the concept of double sum. Assuming the function I am trying to integrate is over x and y can i do the following,

```
result=0;
for i=1:0.1:x
for j=1:0.1:y
fun(i,j)= x(i).*y(j)*0.1^2; %the function I want to integrate times the increment
result = result + fun(i,j);
end
end
```

Also does anyone know what would the best increment be to best approximate the integral?
I appreciate any advice !

Comment: you might find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696212/nested-numerical-integration/19700135#19700135

Comment: side note: you should really vectorize your code.

Answer (score 0):

Numerical integration is a rather complex subject. Probably, the best standard option would be to use (http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html#btdgcqq)

```
result = integral2(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)
```

If you're interested in numerical integration in general, please take a look at Wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration). For specific implementations, Numerical Recipes is a good reference point (http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/linearalgebra/NumericalRecipiesInC/  , sorry, no Matlab version there)